# Failed to create an instance of... via deferred binding

Tags: java, html, gwt

I'm following this guide trying to get a database for my chrome packaged app: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/wiki/DataServiceUserGuide

I have added `gwt-html5-database.jar` to my classpath (it shows up under Referenced Libraries), I put `<inherits name="com.google.code.gwt.database.Html5Database" />` in my gwt.xml.

I created MyDataService.java in the .client package, it contains:

> package com.example.myproject.client;
>
> import com.google.code.gwt.database.client.service.*;
>
> @Connection(name = "myDatabase", version = "1.0", description = "My
>   Database", maxsize = 10000) public interface MyDataService extends
>   DataService {
>
> @Update("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable ("
>               + "id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
>               + "adate INTEGER")   void initDatabase(VoidCallback callback); }

In my main class Test.java (in client package), I have

> package com.example.myproject.client;
>
> import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint; 
>   import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
>
> public class Levels implements EntryPoint { 
>   MyDataService dbService = GWT.create(MyDataService.class);
>   public void onModuleLoad() { } }

I believe I followed the instructions exactly, yet every time I run my app it doesn't work and says `[ERROR] [Test] Failed to create an instance of 'com.example.myproject.client.Test' via deferred binding`

If I remove the `MyDataService dbService = GWT.create(MyDataService.class);`, it loads, so I think the problem is there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of `GWT` are you using? I have the same issue with 2.4 version, but everything works fine in 2.0. Check out this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/issues/detail?id=33&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20API%20Rel%20Owner%20Summary) and [BuildingFromSource](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/wiki/BuildingFromSource) Wiki page of `gwt-mobile-webkit` project. It seems that library is simply not compatible with latest versions of `GWT`.